# when will google revert back page rank after i cleared network unrechable error

Tags: google-search-console

1. For the past one month i was getting network unreachable error.
2. I contacted my web hosting and they said that google bots were blocked if it were causing more traffic.
3. And then they witelisted google bots.
4. Now the errors did not appear but my ranking and search results went down to more than 6 pages or they did not appear at all.
5. Now google is able to read my robots and sitemap. Just yesterday.

when will search results and page rank gets to its previous positions? like it were before a month?

Most links did not appear in google search result.

Comment: Has Piers answered your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt it will revert back straight away, especially as the host was unreachable. However, if you had a fairly high PR, then over time it might creep back up.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Piers.

There are a few things you might be able to do to let Google know that the host is now reachable. Visit Google's website, and re-add the main URL's that are no longer appearing in Google, this'll let Google Bot know that you want these URL's to be indexed, or re-indexed. Note that performing this step does not guarantee any of those URL's will be indexed.

Next, share some of your links. If Google can see that some of your links on other websites are being clicked on, and people are visiting your site from other websites, this should help boost your sites ranking a little.

Apart from the obvious steps that anyone would need to take to get their site listed in Google, there's not much you can do except to wait.